# Import/Export CSV from SQLite from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I am trying to figure out an eazy way to load CSV file into SQLite DB using System.Data.SQLite

I saw commandline way to do that i.e `.Import mydata.csv mytable`

But I need to do this via C# code. Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create `OleDbConnection` to CSV file (just google it, it is very easy) then load rows to DataSet, then put that dataset into Sqlite by `SqliteConnection`. Few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [file helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library if you want also.And well use the ado.net functionality too.