# How to import file with SQLitePCL

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using SQLitePCL to create a database and I want to read in a csv file.  However, I get an exception when I go to `Prepare` any SQLite `'dot-command'` such as

`.import file.csv table`

Is there any way to import CSV files with SQLitePCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I was unsatisfied with the existing answers and wanted a simple portable import using a PCL of SQLite.  For most of my code I've used SQLitePCL.Pretty and tried to import batches of 500 records at a time via `INSERT` and the `PrepareStatement` method - this was horrendously slow.  Luckily, since SQLitePCL.Pretty relies on SQLitePCL.raw, I was able to mimic the SQLite `shell.c` commands for importing, and this is very fast (add your own error handling).

```
var _dbname = "my.db";
var filename = "myfile.csv";
var hasHeaderRow = true;
var tablename = "MyTable";
sqlite3 db;
raw.sqlite3_open(_dbname, out db);
raw.sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN");
sqlite3_stmt stmt;

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string line;
    if (hasHeaderRow)
        file.ReadLine();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " VALUES (" + String.Join(@",", SanitizeSql(line.Split(delimiter))) + ");";
        raw.sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, out stmt);
        raw.sqlite3_step(stmt);
        var rc = raw.sqlite3_reset(stmt);
        raw.sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        stmt.Dispose();
    }
}
raw.sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT");
db.Dispose();
```

### Old Answer

The `"dot-commands"` are only available through the sqlite command line shell, and hence, are not available through any sqlite DLL.

Importing CSVs can be done - just search SO for other sqlite-C# CSV import questions. You'll get answers about using FileHelpers, StreamReader, OleDbConnection... See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386074/import-export-csv-from-sqlite-from-c-sharp-code) for instance or [this example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom).

You could also invoke the sqlite binary through a C# `Process` and pass in the `"dot-commands"` as RedirectionInputs (or in .sql files).